# Code to help change data in the SQL Server from lower case to upper case?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I require help to use data from the SQL Server to extract it then decrpyt it, convert it to capital and then encrypt it and send back to database. Is there code to help upper case the columns in the database?

```
// connection string
static string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tmsdbConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

protected Cryptography a = new Cryptography();

protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
    // Response.Write("Connection Established");
    this.getdataTable();
    this.getDataSet();

    // retrieve data
    SqlCommand command;

    String sql, Output = " ";
    sql = "SELECT applicantId, fullName, idNumber, idType, nationality, race, gender, birthDate, highestEducation, spokenLanguage, getToKnowChannel FROM applicant";

    // command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT applicantId, fullName, idNumber, idType, nationality, race, gender, birthDate, highestEducation, spokenLanguage, getToKnowChannel FROM applicant");

    Cryptography c = new Cryptography();
    lblRecords.Text = c.encryptInfo(lblRecords.Text);
}
```

These are the database methods:

```
public DataTable getDataTable(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Connection = getDBConnection();
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    cmd.Connection.Close();

    return dt;
}

public DataSet getDataSet(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Connection = getDBConnection();
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
    cmd.Connection.Close();

    return ds;
}
```

and these are the cryptography methods:

```
public string encryptInfo(string inputText)
{
    cipherData = AES_256.encryptStringToBytes(inputText, keyBytes, ivBytes);
    string userinfo64Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherData);
    return userinfo64Text;
}

public string decryptInfo(string outputText)
{
    byte[] inputbytes = Convert.FromBase64String(outputText);
    string plainText = AES_256.decryptStringFromBytes(inputbytes, keyBytes, ivBytes);
    return plainText;
}
```

Comment: UPPER function? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/upper-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You haven't actually explained the issue. What happens when you run this code? Normally this can be achieved by running a single `UPDATE` statement but it's unclear whether the data is actually encrypted

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in SQL Server Function called UPPER:

SELECT UPPER('myvalue')